# discord python bot api call with input error?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I'm trying to use an api call with user input and I have got an error that hasn't been solved in about 30 minutes of trying. I'm completely stuck, I used an api call before but without user input (showed bitcoin current price) and it worked perfect so I'm not sure what has gone wrong here.

If you can fix this, it would be very grateful, but if possible also explain what was wrong so I'll learn for next time thanks.

```
@client.command()
async def ipinfo(ctx, ip):
    url = ('http://ip-api.com/json/' + ip)

    response = requests.get(url)
    country = response.json()['country']
    city = response.json()['city']
    embed = discord.Embed(color=discord.Color.red(), title="IP info for " + ip)
    embed.add_field(name="Country", value=f'{country}', inline=False)
    embed.add_field(name="City", value=f"{city}", inline=False)

    await ctx.send(embed=embed)
```

I can provide the error message I get if needed, thanks for any help!

Comment: The error message would be helpful, otherwise it is unclear what is wrong

Answer (score 0):

i worked it out i needed to add ip and ipinfo as aliases thank you.